# ASP.NET Web API multiple RoutePrefix

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing, attributerouting

The opensource [Attribute Routing](http://attributerouting.net/#route-prefixes) allows to have multiple route-prefixes.
Why does ASP.NET Web API 2.0 does not allow to have multiple RoutePrefix().

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v1/{abc}/Entity")]
[RoutePrefix("api/v1/{abc}/{xyz?}/Entity")]
public class MyApiController : ApiController
{
   [Route("")]
   public IHttpResult Get()
   {
      return Ok("Hello World");
   }
}
```

Comment: You can add multiple RoutePrefix attribute on WebApiController. See https://3btechtalk.wordpress.com/2017/05/07/defining-multiple-route-prefix-in-asp-net-web-api-attribute-routing/

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can add a route to the action method also overriding the RoutePrefix with a "~"

example:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v1/{abc}/Entity")]
public class MyApiController : ApiController
{
   [Route("")]
   [Route("~/api/v1/{abc}/{xyz?}/Entity")]
   public IHttpResult Get()
   {
      return Ok("Hello World");
   }
}
```

Notice the line: **[Route("~/** api/v1/{abc}/{xyz?}/Entity")]

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer?  Multiple route prefixes could help avoid multiple `[Route]` attributes for each method and go a long way to helping ease maintenance on a large api controller