# Multiple route point to same web api action

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I would like to point two different routes to same Get action method

```
 [Authorize]
 [Route("{sportType}")]
 [Route("{sportType}/{regular}")]
 public async Task<Player> Get(string sportType, string regular)
 {
  ...
```

Is that possible to specify something like this above? Or do I need to create a separate action?

Above code gives me the following error

```
 No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [assigning-multiple-routes-to-the-same-controller-or-action-in-asp-mvc-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35296018/assigning-multiple-routes-to-the-same-controller-or-action-in-asp-mvc-6)

Comment: You can do it that way as long as you configure the routes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34213482/multiple-routes-on-a-controller

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
 [Authorize]
 [Route("{sportType}/{regular?}")]
 public async Task<Player> Get(string sportType, string regular)
 {
  ...
```

This may help you as well: [Attribute routing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)

Comment: Hi, with this code, when I put sporttype and regular in url, it hits the action method. But if I dont specify regular, I get the same no http resource error. The above code totally make logical sense and so I am really surprised why  it couldn't be working