# How can I expose a webApi method with multiple different URLs?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

In MVC.net `APIController`, I have a method and want to access this method through more than two different URLs from outside. How is it possible and what would the be the best approach?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit on what you mean by accessing by multiple outside URLs?  Do you want multiple URI endpoints for your site to route to a single controller action method?  It might also help to explain why you need this and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hi Alec, Yes I want multiple URI endpoints for your site to route to a single controller action method. I have a controller method and want to excess one url https:// localhost/api/GetStock and other https:// localhost/api/StockStatus as so on.

Comment: Looks like this might fit what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34213482/multiple-routes-on-a-controller